# Getting a 404 on **some** Joomla pages with nginx

Tags: nginx, joomla

*Joomla 2.5, PHP 5.3.3 (fpm-fcgi), nginx 1.4.2*

Nginx is up & running, I can access my site's home page & other site URLs that end index.php just fine.

However when I browse to a Joomla category whose URL is in the form: http://www.mysite.com/index.php/features/modules I always get a 404.

Articles seem to work fine too (in the form http://www.mysite.com/index.php?Itemid=404) it just appears to be categories where "index.php" isn't involved.

Can anyone suggest what I need to add to my nginx conf to fix this please?

Thanks,

Steve

Comment: Have you checked your http redirect ?

Comment: Tell Joomla to stop putting `/index.php` in your URLs. Problems solved.

Comment: Nginx is looking for a page located at `/index.php/features/modules`, but since you don't have a directory called `index.php`, it returns a 404.

Comment: Thanks all - but whilst what you say makes sense what I don't understand is how to *fix* the problem!  ;-)

> Have you checked your http redirect ?

Umm...

> Tell Joomla to stop putting /index.php in your URLs

Umm...

Thanks again.

Steve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Nginx, you need to modify the default configuration file to include:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$request_uri;
}
```

This enables the SEF URLs in Joomla to work.

Comment: Fantastic, that was precisely it!  Thanks @betweenbrain

Comment: You're very welcome!